# SolrNet proper mapping approach

Tags: dynamic, mapping, field, solrnet

I have a rather "complex" scenario where I need to be able to handle information from n-number of sources - each with their own structure. I've built a flexible "black box" for data-transformation purposes, which makes it possible to describe which columns/attributes are available for a given source. It also makes it possible to create multi-value attributes whereas any number of columns may be aggregated and indexed into, say, a Solr  field.

I'd like to be able to handle this as flexible as possible and therefore I'd like to use the various mapping-approaches made available through SolrNet. Having read the "Solr Mapping Document" it seems that "fully loose mapping" might provide what I'm looking for.

Now, just to make sure I understand this correctly: would I still have the possibility to provide, say, "str_title" as the key in the Dictionary and, say, "A Title" as the value in the Dictionary and it would be correctly mapped to the  declaration mentioned above?

I really appreciate if anybody could help me with this as this will have implications on how to continue...

Hope this makes sense:)

Answer (score 2):

Yes the fully loose mapping would provide you ability to define the mapping as you have described and get the expected Solr index results.

**Edit:**

You can do the following, which will map on both sides...

```
 <dynamicField name="str_*" type="string" ... />
```

And then map as the following, which will work for both inserting and retrieving documents from the index.

*Traditional Mapping:*

```
 [SolrField("str_")]
 Dictionary<string, object> myDynamicStrings { get; set; }
```

You can then add to the dictionary items just like the following:

```
myDynamicStrings.Add("title", "A title");
```

*Fully Loose Mapping:*

```
  Dictionary<string object> myDynamicFields { get; set; }
  myDynamicFields.add("str_title", "A title");
```

The same will hold for parsing/accessing results from a Solr query.

Comment: Hi Paige! Sounds great but I'd like to add some stuff to my original posting as it seems to have disappeared:( I assumed that the schema.xml file contained a dynamicField declaration mapping "str_*" to, say, a type="string". So what you're confirming is that if i provide key="str_title" and value="A Title" this WILL be successfully mapped by the loose mapping provided by SolrNet?

Comment: Please see edit for an example... Also if you edit your question and wrap ticks ` ` around your code snippets they will show up.

Comment: @PaigeCook : this answer is correct, but I think Kodo is asking about the "fully loose mapping" option as described in http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Mapping#Fully_loose_mapping , i.e. using directly a dictionary instead of a custom class with SolrField attributes (and yes, that will work as expected too)

Comment: @MauricioScheffer Good point, I lost sight of the "fully loose mapping" in my answer. I have updated it to include both. Thanks.